# HTML: Table and Scripts

Tags: html

I want to write script like this once click on a button it has to add a new row to the existing table

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html> 
    <head> 
     <script>
      function myFunction() { 
       <tr><td></td></tr>
      }
     </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
     <table border="1" id="mytable"> 
      <tr> <td>row 1, cell 1</td> <td>row 1, cell 2</td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td>row 2, cell 1</td> <td>row 2, cell 2</td> </tr> 
     </table> 
     <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> 
    </body
    </html>
```

Plesae help how i can do it?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function myFunction()
{
<tr><td></td></tr>
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
</html>

Comment: Please check this one
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

Try using the javascript `insertRow()` method.

Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

Working example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_table_insertrow

Comment: Thank you so much i got it.

Is samething possible in ASP.net

Comment: Thank you guys i want know one more things
how can insert Combo in in myFunction() sothing like this

function myFunction() { 
    str=document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML;
    newstr='<tr><td> 
<option value="ACT">ACT</option>
<option value="NSW">NSW</option>
<option value="NT">NT</option>
<option value="QLD">QLD</option>
<option value="SA">SA</option>
<option value="TAS">TAS</option>
<option value="VIC">VIC</option></td><td>row n cell 2</td></tr>';
    document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML=str+newstr;
}

Comment: `code`function myFunction() { 
    str=document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML;
    newstr='<tr><td> 
<option value="ACT">ACT</option>
<option value="NSW">NSW</option>
<option value="NT">NT</option>
<option value="QLD">QLD</option>
<option value="SA">SA</option>
<option value="TAS">TAS</option>
<option value="VIC">VIC</option></td><td>row n cell 2</td></tr>';
    document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML=str+newstr;
}

Answer (score 1):

Try the function like:

```js
    function myFunction() { 
        str=document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML;
        newstr='<tr><td><select><option value="ACT">ACT</option> <option value="NSW">NSW</option> <option value="NT">NT</option> <option value="QLD">QLD</option> <option value="SA">SA</option> <option value="TAS">TAS</option> <option value="VIC">VIC</option></select></td><td>row n cell 2</td></tr>';
        document.getElementById('mytable').innerHTML=str+newstr;
    }
```

```html
    <table border="1" id="mytable"> 
        <tr> <td>row 1, cell 1</td> <td>row 1, cell 2</td> </tr> 
        <tr> <td>row 2, cell 1</td> <td>row 2, cell 2</td> </tr> 
    </table> 
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/QYg5a/1

You can also try it like http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/

Comment: Thank you so much i got it.

Is samething possible in ASP.net

Comment: Thank you guys i want know one more things
how can insert Combo in in myFunction() sothing like this

Comment: @Rajiv Test the above changes in my answer.

Comment: Can i insert this combo box dynamically means once double click on dynamically added cell(td) it will show the combo box is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

```js
   function addRow(tableID) { 
  
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID); 
  
            var rowCount = table.rows.length; 
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); 
  
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); 
            var element1 = document.createElement("input"); 
            element1.type = "checkbox"; 
            element1.name="chkbox[]"; 
            cell1.appendChild(element1); 
  
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1); 
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount + 1; 
  
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2); 
            var element2 = document.createElement("input"); 
            element2.type = "text"; 
            element2.name = "txtbox[]"; 
            cell3.appendChild(element2); 
  
  
        }
```

```html
    <BODY> 
  
    <INPUT type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
  
    <TABLE id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1"> 
        <TR> 
            <TD><INPUT type="checkbox" name="chk"/></TD> 
            <TD> 1 </TD> 
            <TD> <INPUT type="text" /> </TD> 
        </TR> 
    </TABLE> 
  
    </BODY>
```

Try this if it fulfill's your requirement

Answer (score 0):

try this:here tbl is the id of your table to which you want to insert the new row.

```
 $("#add_row").click(function () {
   var new_row = "<tr><td>Test1</td><td>Test2</td></tr>";
   $("#tbl").append(new_row);
 });
```